# how can i jump one layout to second layout in same tab layout

Tags: android

> hello expert,
>   i am building one application where i am use tab layout
>   how can i jump one layout to second layout in same tab in tab layout when i click button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to tablayout tutorial [click here](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=tablayout%20in%20android)